# Getting SQLAlchemy to issue CREATE SCHEMA on create_all

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a SqlAlchemy model with a schema argument like so:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Road(Base):
  __tablename__ = "roads"
  __table_args__ = {'schema': 'my_schema'}
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

When I use `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` it correctly issues a `CREATE TABLE` with the schema name on the front like so `CREATE TABLE my_schema.roads (` but Postgresql rightly complains that the schema doesn't exist.

Am I missing a step to get SqlAlchemy to issue the `CREATE SCHEMA my_schema` or do I have to call this manually?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and believe the "cleanest" way of issuing the DDL is something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateSchema

event.listen(Base.metadata, 'before_create', CreateSchema('my_schema'))
```

This will ensure that before anything contained in the metadata of your base is created, you have the schema for it. This does, however, not check if the schema already exists.

You can do `CreateSchema('my_schema').execute_if(callback_=check_schema)` if you can be bothered to write the `check_schema` callback ("[Controlling DDL Sequences](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/ddl.html#controlling-ddl-sequences)" on `should_create` in docs). Or, as an easy way out, just use `DDL("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS my_schema")` instead (for Postgres):

```
from sqlalchemy import DDL

event.listen(Base.metadata, 'before_create', DDL("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS my_schema"))
```

Comment: Can I run my migrations for only newly created schema in Postgres?

Comment: @Emu You may want to ask that as a separate question. But you would probably have to check if the schema does not exist – if it does not, create it and run whatever migration you want to. This isn't strictly covered by my answer. You may want to look into a full migrations library e.g. SQLAlchemy Migrate or alembic.

Answer (score 42):

I have done it manually on my db init script like so:

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateSchema
engine.execute(CreateSchema('my_schema'))
```

But this seems less magical than I was expecting.

Comment: `engine.execute`: `NotImplementedError: This method is not implemented for SQLAlchemy 2.0.`

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but are you able to define `engine` here? Do you mean the result of `create_engine`?

Comment: @Joel - try `engine = sa.create_engine(<your_conn_str>)` then `connection = engine.connect()` then `connection.execute(CreateSchema('my_schema'))`

Answer (score 5):

You can iterate through `metadata.tables`, as per [this Github issue comment](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/3914#issuecomment-441936279):

> ```
> from sqlalchemy import event
>
> @event.listens_for(Base.metadata, "before_create")
> def create_schemas(target, connection, **kw):
>
>     schemas = set()
>     for table in target.tables.values():
>         if table.schema is not None:
>             schemas.add(table.schema)
>     for schema in schemas:
>         connection.execute("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS %s" % schema)
>
>
> @event.listens_for(Base.metadata, "after_drop")
> def drop_schemas(target, connection, **kw):
>
>     schemas = set()
>     for table in target.tables.values():
>         if table.schema is not None:
>             schemas.add(table.schema)
>     for schema in schemas:
>         connection.execute("DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS %s" % schema)
> ```

---

[BEFORE EDIT]

I wrote a function that creates the declared schemas based on the accepted answer. It uses the **schema** value from the **__table_args__** dict from each mapped class.

```py
from sqlalchemy import event, DDL


# Import or write your mapped classes and configuration here

def init_db():
    for mapper in Base.registry.mappers:
        cls = mapper.class_
        if issubclass(cls, Base):
            table_args = getattr(cls, '__table_args__', None)
            if table_args:
                schema = table_args.get('schema')
                if schema:
                    stmt = f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {schema}"
                    event.listen(Base.metadata, 'before_create', DDL(stmt))
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

---

Why they won't create schemas by default, as per [Michael Bayers' comment](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/3914#issuecomment-441936277) on [this](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/3914) Github issue:

> [..] **Unfortunately the concept of a "schema" is not very portable across
> databases**. In MySQL, there's no "CREATE SCHEMA"; there's just other
> databases, e.g. "CREATE DATABASE" which the user account will often
> not have access to do, plus there's a lot of other arguments that go
> along with creating a database. In SQLite, there's no "CREATE SCHEMA",
> there's separate files you can attach to. In Oracle, there's no
> "CREATE SCHEMA", there are other user accounts that act as a namespace
> which again have very different permissions/syntax, additionally there
> are synonyms that can refer to other kinds of objects like remote
> tablespaces and such. Only Postgresql and SQL Server link the "schema"
> to a name that corresponds (usually) to "CREATE SCHEMA", and even
> then, those names might be symbolic names to something else, since you
> can put dotted symbols and other expressions into "schema".
>
> The easy way to throw in "CREATE SCHEMA" with your metadata is just a
> simple event, and this is acceptable to add to the docs [...]

Comment: This is a good idea, but do we know (in 2023) why `create_all` doesn't do this itself? Maybe there's a good reason (which I don't know of) why schemas aren't included in `create_all`?

Comment: They think this database feature is not portable and low priority and added the wonfix tag: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/3914

Answer (score 2):

This is a combination of the best of [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22212214/2071807) (using SQLAlchemy events which seems nice), and [this more flexible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66726465/2071807) which doesn't need the schema names hard-coding:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Connection
from sqlalchemy import DDL
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy import Table


@event.listens_for(Table, "before_create")
def create_schema_if_not_exists(target: Table, connection: Connection, **_):
    connection.execute(
        DDL("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS %(schema)s", {"schema": target.schema})
    )
```

This will create the schema specified by a table like this:

```py
class Application(Base):
    __tablename__ = "mytbl"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "myschema"}
```

This works very nicely.

*NOTE: According to [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/ddl.html#sqlalchemy.schema.DDL) you should be able to just do `%(schema)s` and it'll magically work since we're responding to a `Table` event, but it doesn't. If anyone understands what this section of the docs is talking about, I'll happily update this answer!*